# Laravel 5 : artisan workbench : illuminate/support could not be found

Tags: workbench, packagist, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a new package with `php artisan workbench vendor/packagename` but when I run it I get

```
Package workbench created!
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package illuminate/support could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

The `illuminate/support` is present under `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support` so not quite sure what might be causing it.

The generated composer.json file requires the following

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "illuminate/support": "5.0.*"
},
```

Not sure if `illuminate/support` version `5.0` is what's causing the problem?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had to manually amend the `minimum-stability` from `stable` to `dev` within the half-generated package then run `composer update` to complete it.

Comment: Please, put your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

As Laravel 5 is still under development, change your composer.json called "minimum-stability" from stable to "dev" :

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

Then run at your command line

```
composer update
```